# index out of range in table view cellForRowAt for a cell

Tags: swift

I have one view controller that displays that should show songs and artists. Whenever I run my code it gives my a Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range for artists. I am trying to get info from 2 tables in my sql database and they are called search and artist. I did the same thing as I did for search and It works but now that I added artists I crash. any help would be appreciated.

```
var searchActive: Bool = false
var search = [Search]()
var artist = [Artist]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for:  indexPath)
    
    if  (searchActive) {
        cell.textLabel?.text = search[indexPath.row].cleanName
        cell.textLabel?.text = artist[indexPath.row].artistName //CRASH
    } else {
       searchActive = true
    }
    return cell;
}
  
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    return search.count;
}
```

searchBar function:

```
   func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    search = search.filter({ (song) -> Bool in
       return song.cleanName.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
   })
    artist = artist.filter({ (artists) -> Bool in
        return artists.artistName.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
    })
    
    if (artist.count == 0) {
        searchActive = false
    } else {
        searchActive = false
    }
    if(search.count == 0) {
        searchActive = false
    } else {
        searchActive = false
    }
```

Comment: It depends on the number of rows you return with the numberOfRows(inSection: Int) delegate method.  Yet, your cellForRowAt method is problematic because it depends on either of the arrays.

Comment: @ElTomato Ok, I edited it. I tried to fix it but it still crashes

Comment: Show your numberOfRows delegate method.

Comment: @ElTomato Edited it.

Comment: It will of course crash because the number of rows in your table view depends on [search].

Comment: @ElTomato should I replace search.count with a integer?

Comment: Look, you can do whatever you want with your table view as long as indexPath.row in the `cellForRowAt` delegate method is consistent with the number rows in the `numberOfRows(inSection: Int)` delegate method.

Comment: If you are trying to search the songs and the corresponding artist of the respective songs, you probably should not filter artist list with searchtext.

Comment: The app won't crash at the line where cell.textLabel?.text = artist[indexPath.row].artistName as long [Artist] >= [Search] when you update the table view.

Comment: Don't use multiple arrays as table view data source. It causes this kind of errors. Refactor your design

Comment: @vadian Yes I just started over and it works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It will not crash, because if your array is nil or no data it will get managed. In `numberOfRowsInSection` used ternary condition, where it will set maximum count, so it will not crash at `cellForRowAt indexPath` .

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for:  indexPath)
    
    if  (searchActive) {
        cell.textLabel?.text = search[indexPath.row].cleanName
        cell.textLabel?.text = artist[indexPath.row].artistName ?? "No Data"
    } else {
       searchActive = true
    }
    return cell;
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
   if  (searchActive) {
        return search.count > artist.count ? search.count : artist.count
    }
    else{
        return artist.count 
//Note here you can return anything once your search is not active. or just return 0 to show blank results. 

     }

}
```

Hope it works for you!